# Function is not defined error in nodejs. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: node.js, function, module, defined

I created two files, app.js and helpers.js and when I tried to call a function from app.js, I got an error, function is not defined.

The two files are located in the same folder. I think there is a problem the module.exports keyword,

can anyone help me here? Here is the code of the two separate files:

```js
//app.js

const helpers= require('./helpers');


const total= sum(10,20);
console.log("total:",total);
```

```js
//helpers.js

const sum = (a,b)=>{
 return a+b;
}

module.exports={
 sum
};
```

And the error i am getting is:

```
const total= sum(10,20);
             ^

ReferenceError: sum is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\testing\app.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: You are calling `sum` before it's created. If you want to keep the `sum` creation at the same place, you need to make it a function declaration, otherwise you can just move it up.

Comment: it will be `helpers.sum(10,20);` not only `sum`

Comment: ...and that's why we ask for a [mcve]. I got mislead by the code since it was not representative.

Comment: I believe you have to refer to the sum method through the object assigned by the require('./helpers') statement ie const total = helpers.sum(10,20);

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
   //app.js

const helpers= require('./helpers');


const total= helpers.sum(10,20);
console.log("total:",total);

//helpers.js

const sum = (a,b)=> {
    return a+b;
}

module.exports = sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are exporting your function `sum` in `helpers.js` within an object:

```
// helpers.js

// ...

module.exports = {
    sum
};
```

If you want to access it from `app.js` you can either use `helpers.sum(...)` to access it:

```
// app.js

const helpers = require('./helpers');


const total = helpers.sum(10, 20);
console.log("total:", total);
```

... or you can use object deconstruction in the `require` line:

```
// app.js

const { sum } = require('./helpers');

// ...
```

## Update

Sure, the answer you posted does work, but from the name `helpers.js` I assume that you might want to put multiple helper functions into that file. Then, you must use an object export - as mentioned above - in order to export all helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit the way to export the `sum` function to:

```
module.exports = sum;
```

That's because when you define:

```
module.exports = {...}
```

it means you're exporting an object, not a function.

Usage:

```
const sum= require('./helpers');

const total= sum(10,20);
console.log("total:",total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a my answer.

I just needed to replace the **helpers** keyword with **sum** keyword in the first line of **app.js** and I also removed the curly braces around **sum** in **helpers.js** as per other's advice.

The correct code is below

```
//app.js

const sum= require('./helpers');
const total= sum(10,20);

console.log("total:",total);
```

and

```
//helpers.js

const sum = (a,b)=>{
return a+b;
}
module.exports=sum;
```